# How to select an element using selenium which does not contain a particular class

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I have the following HTML code.

```
<ul class="options">
    <li class="first popover-options ">data</li>
    <li class="first popover-options disabled">data2</li>
    <li class="first popover-options ">data3</li>
</ul>
```

I need to select the element with class="first popover-options", that is it should not contain disabled. How to do this using selenium in java?

Comment: `select the element` but there are multiple elements with `with class="first popover-options"`

Comment: there are two element with mentioned class , data and data3 , which one you want to select ?

Comment: @DebanjanB , i need to select any element , the only requirement is that it should not have disabled. Their is no specific requirement to select any of data or data3. it can select any of the two.

Comment: @cruisepandey It can be any of the two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your question *to identify any of the element with `class="first popover-options"` which should not contain disabled* as per the HTML you have shared you can create a *List* of the elements matching the criteria using either of the following solutions:

- Using *cssSelector*:

  ```
  for (WebElement element:driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("ul.options>li.first.popover-options:not(.disabled)"))) 
  {
      //perform any action with the elements from the list
  }
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  for (WebElement element:driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='options']//li[@class='first popover-options']"))) 
  {
      //perform any action with the elements from the list
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this **code** :

```
List<WebElement> ListEle=  driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("li.first popover-options"));
for (WebElement tempEle : ListEle) {
    if(tempEle.getText().contains("Data"))
     {
       tempEle.click();
     }    
   }
```

Note that it will select Data from the drop down , if you want to select any other item from drop down , you can have it by replacing the code at this level : `tempEle.getText().contains("Data")`

Comment: Thanks but the data content was dynamic , so that was a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can select multiple element using `LIST` and then choose operation on your selected items.

Sample code is like this:

```
List<WebElement> ListEle=  driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='options']//li[@class='first popover-options']"));
for (WebElement tempEle : ListEle) {
    if(conditions)
     {
       //statemnets
       Break;
     }    
   }
```